# How to render child object from a parent object in the materialUI select dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am creating ReactJS application in which i want to render the child objects from the parent object in dropdown using materialUI select. I tried to implement it by iteration over the object using map() function but i am not getting value when i click on the dropdown.

Here is my source code for creating dropdown.

```
import React from "react";
import { Select, MenuItem, FormControl, InputLabel } from "@material-ui/core";
import "./CamSelect.css"

export default class CamSelect extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        currentLocation: localStorage.getItem("location"),
        data: [
            {
                location: "abc",
                link: [
                    {name: "cam1", url: "https://...."},
                    {name: "cam2", url: "https://...."}

                ]
                
            },
            {
                location: "xyz",
                link: [
                  {name: "cam1", url: "https://...."},
                ]
                
            },
        ],
        selected: '',
      
    };

  }


  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ selected: event.target.value, name: event.target.name });
  };
  renderOptions() {
    return this.state.data.map((dt, i) => {
      if(this.state.currentLocation == dt.location){
        dt.link.map(lnk => {
          console.log(lnk.name)
        return (
            <MenuItem
                label="Select a camera"
                value={lnk.url}
                key={i}
                name={lnk.name}
            >
                {lnk.name}
            </MenuItem>
             )
            })
            }
          }
    )
        };
      
  
  render() {
    return (
      <FormControl className="camera-select" style={{ minWidth: "100px"}}>
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label" style={{color:"white"}}>Cam</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
          id="demo-simple-select"
          className="camera-text-color"
          value={this.state.selected}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        >
          {this.renderOptions()}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    );
  }
}
```

My Expectation is that when **currentLocation** will be equal to **location key i.e "abc"** which is in the array object then i want to display **cam1, cam2** value in the dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are iterating over `dt.link.map` you do not return the result, so `renderOptions` also does not return anything => nothing is rendered.

You should have a return here:

```
 return dt.link.map(lnk => {
```

This will return a `JSX.Element[][]`, and you want a `JSX.Element[]`. If there will be only one matching location, you could do `this.state.data.find(dt => this.state.currentLocation == dt.location).map(...)`

Comment: Hi @juliomrc , if there will be one matching location then i am using `this.state.data.find(dt => this.state.currentLocation == dt.location).map(...)` then it is giving me error as **TypeError: this.state.data.find(...).map is not a function**

Comment: You should try to debug more instead of just asking. This is an obvious typo and it should be obvious to you too.

1. What does the error message say? `.map is not a function`.
2. What does that tell us? That whatever comes before the `.map` is not an array.
3. `this.state.data.find(dt => this.state.currentLocation == dt.location).link.map(...)`

Comment: Thanks for the response, Later i was able fixed the issue. as i forgot to add the "Link" array before .map() func.